# 404 error when i hosted my site in server

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-url

Am new to CodeIgniter and I developed a small website using this. My site is working fine in
`localhost`. But when I move my website to the web server, the first Welcome controller is working fine, because I got my first login page. When I click my login(`Welcome/login`). It gives `404 error`(hosting server 404 page). Even it doesn’t give any validation errors.

I hosted this in to a subdomain(`www.subdomain.example.com`)
and I changed base_url, like this domain name. Using `HTACCESS` file for rewriting url.

I changed the `$index_page=“index.php”` to `$index_page=”“`, for removing index.php from URL.
 This working well in localhost. On the server I checked with $index_page then it gives CodeIgniter 404 error page.

The only difference with my localhost is, I hosted it in a subdomain. It may be problem with `.htaccess`, which looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>'
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Post your .htaccess file, for starters, as well as the path that you are trying to access on your host (you said there was a subdomain).

Comment: RTM -> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 2):

Did you update your HTACCESS to forward request to the index.php file? You cannot just set $index_page to ''. If www.subdomain.example.com/index.php/Welcome/login appears you might just  need to add this to your HTACCESS file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Word of advice would be to never use capitalized controller names or any caps in a url period. Linux OS is case sensitive whereas a Windows OS is not. If you test locally on Windows your urls would work just fine, however if you pushed it to a Linux server your urls most likely will not work. To test this try going to www.subdomain.example.com/welcome/login

Comment: thanks for your answer.this url is allso giving 404.i posted my htaccess file and can you please check it.

Comment: Does your new server have mod rewrite enabled?

Comment: If your config.php file has **$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';** try to to set it to **$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';** I have had better luck with it. Also after adding this new HTACCESS file to the server did you remember to restart the Apache service?